# tensorflow gpu Resource Exhausted during model definition

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, gpu

I get **ResourceExhaustedError** from tensorflow not during training but during my model definition, so che classic suggestion "decrease batch size" do not makes sense in this case.

Here is my model definition:

```
def build_net(input_shape=(400, 300, 3),output_class_count=6):
    model=keras.Sequential([
        layers.Input(shape=input_shape,name='Input'),
        layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1,activation='relu',padding='same',name='C5'),
        layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1,activation='relu',padding='same',name='C7'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=3, strides=2,name='MP8'),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(512, activation='relu',name='F10'),
        layers.Dropout(rate=0.5),
        layers.Dense(units=output_class_count,activation='softmax',name='Output')])
    return model

model=build_net()
```

I have already used this code:

```
gpu_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for device in gpu_devices:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(device, True)
```

My `nvidia-smi` output is:

[image]

So the memory is not even completely full.

Here are the stats of the error.

```
Limit:                     10117251072
InUse:                      7773144576
MaxInUse:                   7773144832
NumAllocs:                          22
MaxAllocSize:               3886415872
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0
```

Here is the Error:

```
/tmp/ipykernel_19436/1499846676.py in build_mini_alexnet(input_shape, output_class_count)
     14         layers.Dense(512, activation='relu',name='F10'),
     15         layers.Dropout(rate=0.5),
---> 16         layers.Dense(units=output_class_count,activation='softmax',name='Output')])
     17     return model

/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    585     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    586     try:
--> 587       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    588     finally:
    589       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend.py in random_uniform(self, shape, minval, maxval, dtype)
   1920     return tf.random.uniform(
   1921         shape=shape, minval=minval, maxval=maxval, dtype=dtype,
-> 1922         seed=self.make_legacy_seed())
   1923 
   1924   def truncated_normal(self, shape, mean=0., stddev=1., dtype=None):

ResourceExhaustedError: failed to allocate memory [Op:AddV2]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Think about the number of parameters of your model, its a lot and probably does not fit in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by forcing to build the model with the cpu.

```
with tf.device("cpu:0"):
  model=build_net()
```

Comment: So how many parameters are there in your model?

Comment: About 500M parameters